# java bonecp connection-pool handling issue

Tags: java, connection-pooling, bonecp

I can't find anywhere is web 
code example to how i enable the connection watch
because i get this message in log

```
153624 [com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer] WARN 
com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition - BoneCP    detected 
an unclosed connection and will now attempt to close it 
for you. You should be closing this connection in your 
application - enable connectionWatch for additional debugging assistance.
```

this is my definition:

```
BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
Class.forName(loc.driver);  // load the DB driver
config.setJdbcUrl(loc.url); // set the JDBC url
config.setUsername(loc.user);           // set the username
config.setPassword(loc.password);               // set the password
config.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(5);
config.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(10);
config.setPartitionCount(5);
config.setAcquireIncrement(5);
//config.setCloseConnectionWatch(true);
connectionPool = new BoneCP(config);
```

i also used the:

```
 config.setCloseConnectionWatch(true);
```

but it didn't give me additional debugging assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old and likely already resolved, but to get your debug information you also need to set the `setCloseConnectionWatchTimeout` or `setCloseConnectionWatchTimeoutinMs`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's always helpful to add answers, no matter how old the questions are (provided the answers are helpful). This certainly helped me.